# Rogue smart house locks family in the house to ensure they're eating healthy (comedic tone)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking to find a science fiction short story in which a rogue smart house locks the family in, to ensure that they engage in healthy behaviour.  I seem to recall the focus was on weight loss.  The tone was mostly comedic, and I recall that it ends with the family thinking they'd be free before the AI notices another health issue, implying they'll remain trapped.

Comment: I know we've had this one before...

Comment: For what it is worth, I remember it as it being a more or less humanoid robot that they purchased, not it being the house.

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 8):

I was wrong about us having had it before. I suppose I must have read it on my own. It is "[The Iron Chancellor](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/19368706-the-iron-chancellor)" by Robert Silverberg.

> A robot controls a family’s diet with disturbing exactitude in this 1958 novella by the Hugo and Nebula Award-winning author—with a new forward. Celebrated author Robert Silverberg was twenty-two years old when he wrote The Iron Chancellor, his second contribution to the pioneering science fiction magazine Galexy [sic]. It tells the story of a man who purchases a robot to help himself and his family lose weight. The scheme goes awry as the robot assumes totalitarian control over the household.

It can be read in the [May 1958 issue of *Galaxy* magazine](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v16n01_1958-05/page/n121/mode/2up). Here are some excerpts:

> The Carmichaels were a
> pretty plump family, to begin with. Not one of the
> four of them couldn’t stand to shed
> quite a few pounds. And there happened to be a super-special on roboservitors at one of the Miracle
> Mile roboshops — 40% off on the
> 2061 model, with adjustable caloric-intake monitors.
>
> …
>
> Carmichael gazed sourly at the
> gimmicked control-box of the privacy field. The robot had them utterly hemmed in. The reversed
> privacy field made it impossible
> for them to leave the house; it cast
> a sphere of force around the entire detached dwelling. In theory,
> the field could be penetrated from
> outside, but nobody was likely to
> come calling without an invitation.
> Not here in Westley. It wasn’t one
> of those neighborly subdivisions
> where everybody knew everybody
> else. Carmichael had picked it for
> that reason.
>
> …
>
> “Yes! Yes! And the original program I had taped into you was
> supposed to reduce me from 192
> to 180,” Carmichael crowed triumphantly. “So I’m finished with
> you, as long as I don’t gain any
> more weight. And so are the rest
> of us, I’ll bet. Ethel! Myra! Joey!
> Upstairs and weigh yourselves!”
> But the robot regarded him with
> a doleful glare and said, “Sir, I
> find no record within me of any
> limitation on your reduction of
> weight.”
>
> “*What*?”
>
> “I have checked my tapes fully.
> I have a record of an order causing
> weight reduction, but that tape
> does not appear to specify a *terminus ad quem*.”

Search terms that got me there are `site:goodreads.com robot forces family to lose weight`

Comment: Looks like there's scan/transcription error - "terminus ad quern" should be "terminus ad quem".

Comment: @user888379: Would not surprise me. Archive.org has somewhat spotty OCR at times.

Comment: Yeah... "science fiction magazine Galexy" more of that award-winning OCR technology...

Comment: You may also add an image from the magazine "JT": https://s14.knigavuhe.org/2/covers/34876/1-2.jpg
Read the story some ~35 years ago =)